# How to create Android App from Flutter App?

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, dart

I have been working on a flutter app for quite some time now and it is 75% done. The problem is that I need to use a feature that is only available on native android apps. So my question is that is there a way through which I can "convert" my flutter project to an android project? If so how?

PS: My flutter project uses several plugins like google_firebase and location tracking. So will the converted project still work?

Any inputs would be highly useful as I am unable to find any thread on how to do this.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
Writing custom platform-specific code: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: I suppose in your flutter project, you will see both iOS and android projects separately. So you can simply go in the android repository, and make relevant changes. But i am airballing rn.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Ill let you know if it worked:flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/… this link seems promising